# common phrases for a right idea but poor execution

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

What is a relevant phrase for a "right idea but poor execution" because all I can come up with is promised so much ,but delivered so little. I just need something more precise and appealing than that.

Comment: Please tell us more. Where will you use the expression?

Comment: 'Promised so much, delivered so little' is precise, punchy, idiomatic....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consider **a pertinent idea poorly concretized**

> Pertinent: being of striking appropriateness and relevance.
>
> Concretize: Make (an idea or concept) real; give specific or definite form to.

Comment: But hardly a "*common phrase*", which is what was asked for. Matter of fact, googling for it between quotes shows a **single** hit: this answer. This is the first time in 10 years that I've seen a single google hit for any query.

Comment: No sources to quote?

Comment: @Drew - Googling "good idea poorly realized" only shows 409 occurences and ngram indicates that "pertinent" occurs ten times less than "relevant", what explains that the proposed expression is not found. It's surprising me too!.

Answer (score 2):

The following quotes stress the need for good execution, not just a good idea:

> However beautiful the strategy, you should occasionally look at the
>   results.

Sir Winston Churchill

> A strategy, even a great one,  doesn’t implement itself.

Jeroen De Flander

> Building a visionary company requires one percent vision and 99
>   percent alignment.

Jim Collins

[[from an article by Jeroen De Flander](http://jeroen-de-flander.com/strategy-execution-quotes/)].

.....

> None of my inventions came by accident. I see a worthwhile need to be
>   met and I make trial after trial until it comes.
>
> **What it boils down to is one per cent inspiration and ninety-nine per cent perspiration.**

Thomas Edison

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Thomas_Edison)].

Comment: thank you for the suggestions but I needed something shorter and as a phrase to use it as a subtitle for a paper I'm writing

Comment: @SaraBajraktari can you add that detail to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The person in question gets an [A for Effort](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+for+effort):

> *Fig.* acknowledgement for having tried to do something, even if it was not successful. (*Typically: get ~; give someone ~.) *The plan didn't work, but I'll give you an A for effort for trying.*